# Relative path in my web-service project doesn't work

Tags: java, file, web-services, soap, relative-path

I am creating web-service for translating words between two languages. Words are defined in an xml document (dictionary.xml) which is located in the root of project folder. Service works just fine with absolute path, but when testing with relative path there is a FileNotFound exception.

I tried writing just ("dictionary") and it worked in a project where I was exercising parsing xml files.

This is the method:

```
public String translate(String word, String lang1, String lang2) throws XPathExpressionException, FileNotFoundException {
            XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath path = factory.newXPath();
            String expression = "";
            if (lang1.equals("english")) {
                expression = "dictionary/word/english";
            } else if (lang1.equals("spanish")) {
                expression = "dictionary/word/spanish";
            }
            XPathExpression xPathExpression = path.compile(expression);

            File xmlDocument = new File("D:\\JavaLearning\\AssignmentWebService\\Translator\\dictionary.xml");
            InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new FileInputStream(xmlDocument));

            Object result = xPathExpression.evaluate(inputSource, XPathConstants.NODESET);

            NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) result;
            String translatedWord = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                if (lang1.equals("english") && word.equals(nodeList.item(i).getTextContent())) {
                    translatedWord = nodeList.item(i).getNextSibling().getNextSibling().getTextContent();
                } else if (lang1.equals("spanish") && word.equals(nodeList.item(i).getTextContent())) {
                    translatedWord = nodeList.item(i).getPreviousSibling().getPreviousSibling().getTextContent();
                }
            }
            if (translatedWord.equals("")) {
                translatedWord = "Word \"" + word + "\" doesn't exist in our database!";
            }

       return translatedWord;
    }
```

> Error: Caused by: service.FileNotFoundException_Exception:
>   dictionary.xml (The system cannot find the file specified) at

Comment: Are you sure lang1 is either "spanish" or "english"? Otherwise it will be initialized to "", which seems to be the case given your exception.

Comment: Yes, I am sure.
System.out.println(trans.translate("ball", "english", "spanish"));
It works with absolute path.
And I could swear code worked just fine with relative path also... before I went to work, and after I came back and tested it again it showed exception... I spent hours just to find out that it works with absolute path... But I have no idea why not with relative...

Comment: After backslash escaping, `"D:\\JavaLearning\\AssignmentWebService\\Translator\\dictionary.xml"` translates into `D:\JavaLearning\AssignmentWebService\Translator\dictionary.xml`. I'm assuming you're using windows, I'm not sure `D:\ ` is valid. If you paste `D:\JavaLearning\AssignmentWebService\Translator` into the explorer location bar, will it be able to cd to that directory?

Comment: Yes. It goes to the Translator directory. And inside of that directory there is dictionary.xml.